# ErrorPageFilter error in log when trying to handle exception in a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot, error-handling

I've made a small Spring Boot application and now I'm trying to add my own exception handling. I'm having a problem where I get an error in the log even though the app works as expected. The configuration:

- Tomcat 8 (standalone)
- Spring Boot version 1.2.3
- War packaging

The exception handler looks as follows:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody ErrorInfo handleNotFoundRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    return new ErrorInfo(req.getRequestURL().toString(), ex);
}

}
```

My controller that throws the exception:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody
HashMap environment(@PathVariable("id") long id)  {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
    Environment env = environmentService.getEnvironment(id);

    if(env == null) throw new NotFoundException("Environment not found: " + id);

    map.put("environment", env);

    return map;
}
```

My Spring Boot application setup:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
public class QaApiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(QaApiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

*ServletInitializer:*

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder   application) {
    return application.sources(QaApiApplication.class);
}
}
```

*pom.xml*

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
......
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If I do a call that generates the exception I get the correct response, a 404 with the expected JSON. I do however see a *ErrorPageFilter* error in the log:

> 2015-04-09 21:05:38.647 ERROR 85940 --- [io-8080-exec-16]
>   o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter: Cannot forward to error
>   page for request [/environments/1] as the response has already been
>   committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
>   If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may
>   be able to resolve this problem by setting
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

There is no errors on startup / deployment and everything seem to be working as far as I can see. I'm suspecting that there is some default behavior that I've not overridden correctly or so, but I've yet to figure out exactly what.

Any help / tip around this would be greatly appreciated as I've become stuck on what the problem could be.

Comment: Can you explain how you're using war packaging for an external Tomcat when you're not using `SpringBootServletInitializer`? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file I'm a bit confused. Otherwise, I've built a demo project with what you have provided and run it from STS, and I can't reproduce the error message.

Comment: I added that file into the description as well now, to avoid confusion. Did you deploy on a tomcat 8?

Comment: You may be interested in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2745). You're not doing anything wrong in your application; it's a limitation of Boot's error page filter

Comment: Many thanks! The issue seem to be similar indeed, applying a similar workaround removes the ERROR in the log for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you still uses Spring-boot version 1.2.3 (not 1.4.2.RELEASE where [solution provided](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/11d59df3fd71a656a7869ace4303a8d72e6f777c)) then extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and override method `run` as following:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
public class QaApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(QaApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication application) {
        application.getSources().remove(ErrorPageFilter.class);
        return super.run(application);
    }
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up on the same issue with Springboot2.0 app running on WAS Liberty profile. I have disabled the Error Page Filtering with the below configuration in the properties file.
     `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter=off`